# how to change the overload operator [] of an array to ()?

Tags: c++

It’s not convenient for me to work with multidimensional arrays and use this kind of bracket, they greatly complicate the readability of the code.

here is an example of complexity

```
arr[f1][f2][ arr[f1][f2][f3] ];
```

if there are other brackets it will be convenient for me

```
arr(f1)(f2)( arr(f1)(f2)(f3));
```

I would like something more convenient but I do not know anything else.

Comment: Are you asking because the `[]` brackets are more difficult to type on your keyboard or do you actually mean that they are less readable? (because I'd say the opposite is true)

Comment: I don’t know why, but they seem more massive and are read worse, visually.

Comment: What is `arr`? A plain array or a container? (If a container, is it a standard one or did you write it?) *"greatly complicate the readability"* Maybe, but if you switch to `(...)`, everyone else who will read your code will probably hate you. You should get yourself used to `[...]`. *"they seem more massive"* Try using a different font. Or if your IDE draws them in bold font, try disabling the boldness.

Comment: `arr` - is an array

Comment: Then there is no way to use `()` here. Overloading `()` requires `arr` to be a class instance.

Comment: You seem to be asking a purely cosmetic question, which is fine for me. You might walk the pre-processor path to the success you are seeking; admittedly with a few `,` instead of `[]` or `()`.

Comment: To the dark side that path leads. :P

Comment: maybe there is some way to simplify the code with a template, I am ready to use templates for the sake of code readability.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree.

Comment: As already said, you probably should look for a different font/style for your IDE/Editor or use a different editor. Instead of forcing an uncommon style onto the code. While it is perfectly fine to code in whatever way you want in your private code,  you will not do yourself any favors to get used to such an unusual style if you plan to use/learn c++ for later use in a job, because then you will have to program according to their guidelines.

Comment: Introducing variables (and giving them meaningful names) is often a good way to improve readability:  `size_t f = arr[f1][f2][f3]; arr[f1][f2][f];` (I don't know what `f` stands for, and what `arr` returns so coming up with a good name is not possible here). Those variables normally won't produce any overhead, as the compilers can optimize them away.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Consider changing the font in your code editor if you dislike what `[]` looks like.